# xcode send boolean to soap webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, ipad

I am trying to send boolean value to .Net Soap Webservice from IPad application. I couldnt figure out how to send it. I tried true, @"true", 1. but they didn't work. has anybody tried it before? Would you please give me a hint

here is my code. question1,question2,question3,question4,question5 and question6 are boolean values.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<SendData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<containerId>%@</containerId>"
                         "<date_>%@</date_>"
                         "<image1>%@</image1>"
                         "<image2>%@</image2>"
                         "<image3>%@</image3>"
                         "<question1>%@</question1>"
                         "<question2>%@</question2>"
                         "<question3>%@</question3>"
                         "<question4>%@</question4>"
                         "<question5>%@</question5>"
                         "<question6>%@</question6>"
                         "<notes>%@</notes>"
                         "<transDate>%@</transDate>"
                         "<userId>%@</userId>"
                         "<macId>%@</macId>"
                         "<sFileId>%@</sFileId>"                             
                         "</SendData>"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", @"999", @"2013-09-09", @"" ,@"" ,@"" ,@""  ,@"" , @"" , @"" , @"" , @"1", @"notes", @"2013-09-09", @"123", @"mymacid", @"sfileid"];
```

Comment: what does the server expect to be send?How are you sendnig this?Include some code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL someBool = YES; //or NO
NSString *stringBool = someBool?@"true":@"false";
```

After that you can use `stringBool` in your `stringWithFormat`

Comment: only if you'll create NSString from that, for example

    `NSString *stringBool = @"true";`

otherwise use "true" in code instead of "%@"

Comment: Can u provide more information?
What you replaced with what?
And by the way, try to print your `soapMessage` after calling `stringWithFromat`
`NSLog(soapMessage);`

If there is correct values, than your problem not in this string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to input values using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).
Download it and try your boolean values.